# error in SQL syntax with php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to update an encrypted user key in a table in a database.
this is the code in PHP:

```
$new_pass=password_hash($_POST["n_pass"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql="UPDATE users SET password=$new_pass WHERE users.id=1";
```

randomly I get two different error messages:

1. Error: UPDATE users SET
   `password`=$2y$10$5nbnfpmOmvZi8hsNp.RLiOK7tEvtFWr4uPP6UaNUyFnqacB9lQsK.
   WHERE id=1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
   to use near 'WHERE id=1' at line 1
2. Error: UPDATE users SET
   `password`=$2y$10$KhHSVvgr7PqhxWzKzSnuBOU6gEOYoyQXceg8Oh9rKGvqxEAg72jUG
   WHERE id=1 Unknown column
   '$2y$10$KhHSVvgr7PqhxWzKzSnuBOU6gEOYoyQXceg8Oh9rKGvqxEAg72jUG' in
   'field list'

Comment: Prueba esto en tu segunda línea de código: $sql="UPDATE `users` SET `password`='$new_pass' WHERE `id`=1";

Comment: funcionó mil gracias

Comment: @JDVS por favor traduce la pregunta al español para evitar su cierre

Comment: Amigo verdolaga, acá en SOes nos charlamos en español. Como la idea es que la pregunta y la respuesta le sirvan a los demás en el futuro, por fa tradúcela y, si la respuesta que hay te sirvió, márcala como aceptada con el chulito VERDE que tiene al lado :D

Comment: Acabo de traducir la pregunta, no sé si hice bien o no, pero ahí va (falta que alguien la apruebe). ^^

Comment: @Tupi ent estos casos debe ser el autor de la pregunta quien la traduzca, rechacé la edición por eso motivo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por avisar, lo tendré en cuenta la próxima vez. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El detalle esta en que debes colocar en comillas la clave ($new_pass) porque si no SQL lo toma como variable.

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET password='$new_pass' WHERE users.id=1";
```

Así ya te debería funcionar.

Saludos

Comment: Considera por favor que lo ideal es pedirle primero al usuario que traduzca su pregunta para evitar el cierre de la misma

Comment: Entiendo, no sabía